# What is the difference between oc and kubectl commands?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am trying to create a cron job in openshift and having trouble doing this with oc so I am looking for alternatives.

I have already tried: "oc run cron --image={imagename} \ --dry-run=false"
This created another resource. There was no parameter to create a cron job

Comment: Cronjobs work as described in the docs: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already a good answer on how the two platforms overlap. You mentioned there was no parameter to create a cronjob. You can do that with `oc` through the following [(resource)](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html):

```
oc run pi --image=perl --schedule='*/1 * * * *' \
    --restart=OnFailure --labels parent="cronjobpi" \
    --command -- perl -Mbignum=bpi -wle 'print bpi(2000)'
```

Or you can do it through a yaml file like the following:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

And then run:

```
oc create -f cronjob.yaml -n default
```

Comment: When running this I get the error unknown flag: --schedule
Maybe I have the wrong version?

Comment: @rtbilli110 hmm that's odd, try applying this through a yaml file. Check out the template [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html#creating-a-cronjob).

Comment: Im not too sure how to do this... On the openshift origin website I tried Add to Project -> Import YAML/JSON and nothing showed up. Would you know how I can do this through command line or through the openshift origin?

Comment: Sure, copy the yaml file from this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#creating-a-cron-job) and paste into `cronjob.yaml` and then run `kubectl apply -f  cronjob.yaml`

Comment: I dont have kubectl installed. Do you know how to do this? Sorry I am very novice to dev ops.I am using windows

Comment: Not a problem, run `oc create -f cronjob.yaml` instead

Comment: Running the above I get cronjob.yaml does not exist 
When I run: "oc create -f cronjob.yml" I get:
unable to decode "cronjob.yml": no kind "CronJob" is registered for version "batch/v1beta1"

Comment: Did you add the yaml file? Run `oc process -f cronjob.yml -p foo=bar -o yaml | oc apply -f -`. Here you'll be using the oc process to hack your way into a cronjob!

Comment: unknown shorthand flag: 'p' in -p. 

Here is my version of oc if that helps: oc v3.2.1.31
kubernetes: v1.2.0-36-g4a3f9c5

Comment: Your version of `oc` is incredibly out of date. What server version are you using? You should make sure that your using the proper `oc` version for your server. And if your server doesn't support CronJob, you would need to update.

Comment: OpenShift Master:
v3.9.0
Kubernetes Master:
v1.9.1
OpenShift Web Console:
v3.9.0
Then through command line: oc v3.2.1.31

Comment: I got this to work finally. Does anyone know how I can view this cronjob on openshift origin so I can add environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

oc stands for openshift client which is a wrapper created on top of kubectl. It is created to communicate with openshift api server.
It supports all operations that are provided by kubectl and others that are specific to OpenShift like operations on templates, builds, build and development config, image stream etc